# DDD : modeling aggregates

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs, aggregateroot

I'm facing a design problem where i want to model the very same physical object in two different bounded context.

In order to describe my problem as precisly as possible, and even tho i'm aware this is only an implementation detail, i will start with my Event Sourcing mechanism.

### My events storage mechanism

*the following is widely inspired by Greg Young's CQRS document https://cqrs.wordpress.com/documents/ (watch out for the PDF "building an Event Storage" section).*

I have **2 tables**, one called `Aggregates` and another one called `Events` (Note the plural form as these are tables, not objects!) which look like this :

#### *Aggregates* Table

All my aggregates are stored in this table ; it has 3 columns (SO doesnt support the md table formatting so, sorry, i'll go for a list):

- `AggregateId` : basically this table's primary key. I'm using a Guid, as all my aggregates are using one.

  - `AggregateType` : the fully qualified Aggregate's name.
  - `CurrentVersion` : the current aggregate version. An integer that gets incremented every time an event get stored.

#### *Events* Table

Every domain event issued by any Aggregates get stored in there ; it has got 5 columns :

- `AggregateId` : the foreign key to the aggregates' table.
- `SerializedEvent` : the domain event as it was issued by the aggregate but in a serialized form (eg. json)
- `Version` : An integer that gets incremented (for each given aggregate) every time an event get stored.
- `EventDate` : a datetime
- `UserName` : the user that issued the event's producing command

### Example of a domain with 2 bounded contexts

Now let's consider a merchant :

- A merchant **buys products** (that's the job of the purchase department, aka. supply chain department)
- A merchant **sells products** (that's the job of the sales department, in our case let say it's done on a website)

**The purchase department will consider a Product as following :**

- the product is purchasable by one or many suppliers
- the product has a purchase pricing grid, probably different from a supplier to another
- the product is stored in one or many warehouse where it is available (or not) in a given quantity
- the product is therefore subject to inventory

**On the other hand, the sales department will consider the product in a different way :**

- the product has a sales price (and maybe even a sales pricing grid)
- the product has guarantees, sales conditions...
- in an e-commerce context, it would even have publication's related attributes (like pictures, categories, descriptions, user vote and comments...) (so probably )

> that sounds like 2 distinct bounded contexts, right?

*Actually, Product, seen from the website point of view with its pictures, categories and votes attributes, sound to me like a third bounded context, but let's not debate about it for the example's sake...*

Let's now complete this domain example with the domain expert specification saying :

- "A product must have a name"
- "The supply chain department is the one responsible for adding products to the system"
- "As a consequence, the sales department NEVER adds products to the system but instead, it receives a NewProductAdded notification, informing him a new product is available for sales "
- (and probably some other rules like Sales Dptmt can only publish a product on the website once the supply chain Dpt. said this product was available in the ware house. )

  And now i think we have a valid use case.

  *NB : while i'm facing a very similar problem in a real project, this use case is purely abstract and inspired of this Codemotion conference slide http://goo.gl/lMWSFZ.*

### 1 product aggregate per BC => 2 distinct Product AR

So ok, in traditionnal design, I'd probably end up with a big `Product Entity` that would contain attributes related as much to the Sales point of view as to the supply point of view.

But I want to go for a DDD approach, and DDD says that I should protect my invariants within a bounded context.
So, the domain model of a product is different according to wether i'm within the Sales or in the Supply Bounded Context.

As far as i understood it, i should therefore have 2 entities :

- a Product Entity in the Sales BC
- and another Product Entity in the supply BC...

Still for the example's sake, we'll admit that those 2 Product entities were decided to be promoted to the range of aggregate root in their respective BC.

so to sum up we have :

> 2 bounded context
>
> 1 product Aggregate per bounded context

**But this is the very same product right?**

### Designing the `Product AR` in the *Supply Chain BC*

*The following is widely inspired by :*

- *@codescribler's blog post : http://goo.gl/UgYRqq*
- *M. Verraes' conference : http://goo.gl/iVrdZu*

First, let's have a look at my abstract AggregateRoot class :

```
  namespace DomainModel/WriteSide;

  abstract class AggregateRoot
  {
    protected $lastRecordedEvents = [];

    protected function recordThat(DomainEvent $event)
    {
      $this->latestRecordedEvents[]=$event;
      $this->apply($event);
    }

    protected function apply(DomainEvent $event)
    {
      $method = 'apply'.get_class($event);
      $this->$method($event);
    }

    public function getUncommittedEvents()
    {
      return $this->lastestRecordedEvents;
    }

    public function markEventsAsCommitted()
    {
      $this->lastestRecordedEvents = [];
    }

    public static function reconstituteFrom(AggregateHistory $history)
    {
      foreach($history as $event) {
        $this->apply($event);
      }
      return $this;

    abstract public function getAggregateId();

  }
```

Basically, this class holds the ES mechanism.

Now let's have a look at its implementation for Product in the Supply Chain BC :

```
namespace DomainModel/WriteSide/SupplyChain;
use DomainModel/WriteSide/AggregateRoot as BaseAggregate;

Class Product extends BaseAggregate
{
  private $productId;
  private $productName;
  //some other attributes related to the supply chain BC...


  public function getAggregateId()
  {
    return $this->productId;
  }

  private function __construct(ProductId $productId, $productName)
  {
    //private constructor allowing factory methods
  }

  public static function AddToCatalog(AddProductToCatalogCommand $command)
  {
    //some invariants protection stuff
    $this->recordThat(new ProductWasAddedToCatalog($command->productId));
  }

  private function applyProductWasAddedToCatalog(DomainEvent $event)
  {
    $newProduct = new Product($event->productId);
    return $newProduct;
  }

  //more methods there...
}
```

### The flow

*The following is widely inspired by @codescribler's blog post : http://goo.gl/yuIjzf*

1. The UI (a user from the supply chain dpt.) has sent an `AddProductToCatalogCommand(/*...*/)` via the service layer (aka. command bus forwarding the command to its handler),
2. the handler has prepared the Product Aggregate (in other words, brought it to its current state by applying all previous events to it) and passed him the command over.
3. Given no exception was raised (in other word, the Aggregate handled the command properly), **we're now at the point where the handler is requesting the changes the aggregate just applied to itself.**

   **The handler now persists the changes** in the database :

   - it inserts a new row in the `Aggregates` table :
   - AggregateId = ProductId
   - AggregateType = /some/namespace/Product
   - AggregateVersion = 0
   - it inserts a new row in `Events` table :
   - AggregateId = ProductId
   - Event = `ProductWasAddedToCatalog($productId)` (in a serialized form off course)
   - version = 0
4. Persitence went well, so **the handler forwards the event to the service layer** (aka. event bus forwarding the event to its handler**s**) for its subscribers to do their jobs.

> here comes my problem!

One of these subscribers is an event handler issuing a command for the Sales BC Product Aggregates.

```
namespace DomainModel/WriteSide/Sales;
use DomainModel/WriteSide/AggregateRoot as BaseAggregate;

Class Product extends BaseAggregate
{
  private $productId;
  //some other attributes related to the Sales BC, like sales price, guarantees...


  public static function AddAutomaticallyProductToCatalogSinceSupplyChainAddedIt(UpdateSalesCatalogCommand $command)
  {
    // some invariants' protection code here

    $this->recordThat(new ProductWasAutomaticallyAddedToSalesCatalog($command->productId));

  }
}
```

> So now, what is my *$command->productId*?

As Jimmy Bogard well summed it up in http://goo.gl/QHBkSr : *"Each Aggregate has a Root Entity [...] The root Entity has **global identity** and is ultimately responsible for checking invariants"*

Global identity is the key word.

So in my use case, **we have 2 disctinct Aggregates and we therefore should have 2 distincts AggregateRoot's Ids**.

It's even more obvious under the light of the event storage mechanism described above because if both ARs had the same Id, one would receive some events of the other while processing its `public static function reconstituteFrom(AggregateHistory $history)`

> So 2 distinct Ids. But still it's the very same product right? How do i make that explicit?

### Possible solutions

After investigation, i come up with 3 possibles solution. I hope someone will be able to guide me into the right one...

#### Solution 1 : Holding a reference

The sales BC Product Aggregate hold a reference to the supply chain Product Aggregate.

this would look like this :

```
namespace DomainModel/WriteSide/Sales;
use DomainModel/WriteSide/AggregateRoot as BaseAggregate;

Class Product extends BaseAggregate
{
  private $productId;
  private $supplyChainProductId;   //the reference to the supply chain BC Product AR...


  public function getAggregateId()
  {
    return $this->productId;
  }

  //more methods there...
}
```

#### Solution 2 : Using a composite primarey key in the Event Storage

while i currently use the `AggregateId` column as primary key, i could use both `AggregateId` and `AggregateType`.

Since that would allow me to have both Product AR having the same ProductId, this looks like a smell to me ...  Alone because of the concept of AR global identity would be ruined...

#### Solution 3 : using a product *sub-entity* in both AR

Still from Jimmy Bogard's http://goo.gl/QHBkSr, " Entities inside the boundary have local identity, unique only within the Aggregate."

So i could model the sales BC Product Aggregate like following :

```
namespace DomainModel/WriteSide/Sales;
use DomainModel/WriteSide/AggregateRoot as BaseAggregate;

// **here i'd introduce my sub-entity**
use DomainModel/Sales/Product/Entities/Product as ProductEntity;

Class Product extends BaseAggregate
{
  private $_Id;
  private $product;   //holds a ProductEntity instance


  public function getAggregateId()
  {
    return $this->_Id;
  }

  public function getProductId()
  {
    return $this->product->getProductId();
  }

  //more methods there...
}
```

**While this would allow to keep both AR having the same productId, this doesnt really make sense to me since the only way to get an aggregate is by its AR's Id** (and not by the Id of any of its sub-entities).

Tho we could imagine having a sort of mapper on the Query side :

```
namespace DomainModel/QuerySide;

Class ProductMapping
{
  private $productId;
  private $salesAggregateId;
  private $supplyChainAggregateId;
  private $product;   //holds a ProductEntity instance


  public function getSalesAggregateId()
  {
    return $this->salesAggregateId;
  }

  public function getSupplyChainAggregateId()
  {
    return $this->supplyChainAggregateId();
  }

}

Class ProductMappingRepository
{

  public function findByproductId($productId)
  {
    //return the ProductMapping object
  }

  public function addFromEvent(DomainEvent $event)
  {
    //this repository is an event subscriber....
  }

}
```

Beside this ProductMapper, the query side would then only know about the ProductId. Seems all done ...
but this again doesn't look right to me. Can't really say why, it just doesn't !...

### Conclusion

This is a fake use case, and as such, it's probably debatable whether the 2 bounded contexts described above shoud be modelled as such or not.

But i hope i made my point clear, namely how to identify the very same physical object (in that use case, a Product) in 2 different BCs.

> **Thx in advance for ur help!!!**

*NB . While my first Post contained many linguistic misuses and therefore left out many opened doors to interpretation, leading to misunderstanding of the problem i'm trying to solve, i choosed to completly re-edit it. Tho for future reader to understand the previous replies and comments, i leave the first post version below*

## ==================================================================

#### The question as asked Apr 18 at 11:51

let's start straight with the context (taken from this Codemotion conference slide http://goo.gl/lMWSFZ).

Domain expert is a merchant, he buys, sales and shifts Products. He's got :

- an e-commerce web site for sales purpose
- a supply chain department responsible for purchasing purpose
- a logistics department responsible for the shipping

So, we may consider having one Product Aggregate for each bounded context :

- **A Product Aggregate for for the sales context** that will hold properties like sales price, evtl. discount, customer friendly description, pictures, maybe some categories it belongs too etc..
- **A Product Aggregate for the purchase context** that will hold references to the suppliers and their purchasing conditions (eg. pricing by quantity, availabilities etc...)
- **An Item Aggregate for the logistics** context holding properties like size and weight (note that in this context, the aggregate's name is Item and not Product as the logistic department isnt concerned about wether it's a product or a packaging or a palett)

Domain expert also says :

- "the purchase department is the one that insert new Products to the system"
- "once the purchase department has inserted a new product in the system, it must be available for the others"

> Now my question is simple :
>
> how do I reference each aggregate to each other, given it's in the end
>   "the very same Product"?
>
> Should Sales and Logisitics Aggregates contains an PurchasedProductId
>   ? I've been told to be very carefull with external references but ...
>   how else?

**EDIT :**

this question must be seen under the light of an Events Storing pattern, where :

- every Aggregates get stored with its unique Id in an Aggregates Table (where rows are AggregateId, AggregateType, CurrentVersion),
- this unique Id get used as foreign key in an Events Table (that stores all the events that happened to the AR in 3 column : AggregateId, SerializedEvent, Version)

So, if the same ProductId should be used as @Plalx is suggesting it in its reply, the question becomes :

> how can you have 2 Aggregates using the same Id whereas, by definition, an Aggregate is a self-containing Entity and, still by definition, an Entity must have a unique Id?

Comment: You haven't modified your answer according to your last comment yet =P

Comment: i know but still working on it, so I make it very clear. Btw i've been reading yur other answer on "Are entity classes exclusive to one aggregate"here on SO http://goo.gl/t7NvA1

Comment: @I'm not sure where you saw it was my answer, but I did make a comment there.

Comment: yes it wasnt an answer but a useful comment!

Comment: @plalx i published the new version of the question. It's quite long (and this explains why it took me so long) but i hope i closed all possible misinterpretation. Thx again for ur concern!

Comment: I think you missed the fact that every BC is usually completely autonomous and has it's own database. Your main issue seems to go away when you consider that fact.

Comment: @plalx Woowoowoow I indeed never took that option into account, and that would indeed solve my issue!!! So basically i got 2 options : Option1 : one DB per BC || Option2 : same DB and Solution 1 as described above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow, there's lots going on here. Modeling AR is as much an art as it is science!

First bit of advice: don't involve your database when designing your AR. Why? CQRS, AR and event sourcing are all strategic and tactical patterns from DDD. The emphasis is to remove distractions from the modelling process. A database is a distraction (in this case). It may be the root cause of your difficulty here.

Bounded contexts, among other things, are a mechanism to simplify modeling. They should reflect how the various departments view things such as Products/Items. In fact, this model is a good example. The model names reflects the words the business uses in each context. In some ways while they are talking about the same thing, they are different. They mean different things within their respective contexts. Hence the need to model them separately.

What about external references...

An AR can refer to another AR but only in the form of an ID (not necessarily a database key). In practical terms the AR must not contain a reference to another AR within itself, ie. a private variable containing another AR (has a). This is because an AR is only guaranteed to be consistent within it's boundaries.

This brings us to the problem in the question. How do we coordinate these 3 AR from different bounded contexts?

The first approach is to ask whether they are in fact in different bounded contexts. Sometimes these modelling problems are a helpful way of triggering a re-think of the model.

Lets assume for your domain they are right. How do we co-ordinate them?

In this case a process manager and an anti corruption layer would appear to be a good bet. The process manager would listen for product and or item created events. It would then generate the appropriate commands for creating the other entities. The chances are, each context deals with this differently. Hence the need for an ACL. The ACL would be responsible for translating the request into something that makes sense within it's domain. That may be as simple as adding the external ID of the originating AR to the command to create it's AR. Or it may just hold the info in a staging area until various other conditions are met.

At a high level, listen to the events and use them to trigger relevant processes in other bounded contexts. Use a process manager and if needed and ACL.

Finally the storage issue...

I would opt for a simple event storage strategy here. Keep each event in a stream. Use the AR ID to pull back events for any single AR.

For the read model I would use a set of denormalisers that listen in to the event stream. They would then generate a read model tailored to the UI (in this case). That may involve combining info from different BC's. Whatever makes sense for your users.

I have covered some of these ideas in a post on my blog: [4 Secrets to Inter Aggregate Communication](http://danielwhittaker.me/2014/11/22/4-secrets-inter-aggregate-communication-event-sourced-system/).

Anyway I hope this helps.

Comment: i had obviously read ur blog post before and as u can see, my re-edited question mentions you quite often. Hope this re-edited version will catch your attention. anyway, thx again for ur previous concern!

Answer (score 4):

There's no such thing as `PurchasedProductId` IMHO, only `ProductId`. When a new product gets created in the Purchase context, a `ProductCreated { ProductId, ...}` event could be sent to a messaging infrastructure. Other bounded contexts would set up subscribers for that event and upon receiving it and then create and persist their own view of the created `Product`, using the product identity stored in the event.

> "how can you have 2 Aggregates using the same Id whereas, by
>   definition, an Aggregate is a self-containing Entity and, still by
>   definition, an Entity must have a unique Id?"

I'll try to shed some light on this, at least from my understanding. Just like a Bounded Context (BC) is a technical solution to a conceptual problem, such as a Sub Domain, an Aggregate Root (AR) is essentially a tactical (technical) pattern allowing you to craft transactionally consistent boundaries which protects the invariants of an Entity for a specific set of operations. An AR is a specialized representation of an Entity.

Therefore, each `Product` AR implementation in their respective BC is just a different representation of the same Entity, but specialized for it's problem space. Depending on your domain, I guess that you may have an abstract `Product` class living in a shared kernel and used within every BC, but the dependency might also not be worth.

Comment: Thx for ur reply! I wrote `PurchasedProductId` for distinction's sake but i totally agree on ur remark. I also agree on the event dispatching process, and further i forgot to mention I consider the problematic from the Event Sourcing point of view. So if i get you right, the `logisticBC ItemAggregate` and the `salesBC ProductAggregate` would have their own ID (as 1 aggregate = 1 entity by definition) but then hold the ProductId as a reference to the `purchaseBC ProductAggregate` ?

Comment: So aren't we back to holding an external reference to another AR?

Comment: @Developpeurtunisie I think the additionnal identity is useless and just brings noise to the model. I would just use `ProductId`. A product has a different shape and life-cycle in every context, but it's still the same product. It's different for `Item` however, since it isn't necessarily a Product. "So aren't we back to holding an external reference to another AR"... how is that a problem? There's no other way that holding onto a shared identity.

Comment: OMG this topic is friving me nuts but anyway thx again for ur concern! So ok for the logistic BC haveing an ItemAggregate holdng an external reference to Product. And again i agree on this additional Id just polluting the model. So now question is even more simple : how can you have 2 Aggregates using the same Id whereas, by definition, an Aggregate is a self-containing Entity and, still by definition, an Entity must have a unique Id? Am I maybe missing smthg between 2 concepts, Aggregate and Aggregate root? For me AR is a unique abstract class extended by all Aggregates ...

Comment: ... (cont'd) and providing the necessary event storage mechanism.

Comment: I realize i totally misexpressed myself reguarding Aggregate and AggregateRoot, mixing the way I implement it with their definition. Pls dont take it into account.

Comment: @Developpeurtunisie I tried to answer your questions in my edit.

Comment: thx again for ur time! I really appreciate ur efforts and wish I could put this post to Solved... but I can't. I thought as well about an Abstract Product, but this feels to me like a smell... means i am reintroducing coupling whereas the aim is to have nicely decoupled BCs... But instead of inheritance i might dig into Composition, means my AR, with its unique ID, is composed by a ProductEntity, holding the ProductId. But again, i've read that uniqueness of an EntityId shld be granted ... inside its AR only... So Composition would do the contrary... feeling stuck and lost...

Comment: @Developpeurtunisie I'm not sure where you see a problem. You have a concrete `Product` class in a different module/package (one per BC). Classes do not have to extend any abstract class or have any dependencies. You also do not have a concept of a `ProductEntity`, just a `public class Product { ProductId id; ... }` class.

Comment: i'm not trying to introduce a ProductEntity concept, i used this inappropriate word only to distinguish the Aggregate from the entity, but i think this reply gave me a hint, and i will edit the post to see if i got it (finally!!) right.

Answer (score 1):

IMO the question is way too long. If I correctly understand the problem, you have purchasing and sales domains (and BCs) and you have something in common between products in both domains, which is a product itself. You are struggling getting these two together without bringing them into one BC or domain.

Splitting Purchase and Sales into two BCs is logical. BC represents a ubiquitous language and both domains mean different things about one word (product), you mentioned this.

However, the product itself is a physical entity and have some attributes like description, weight, size and picture. These attributes are shared across all the domains and there is no doubts about the meaning of these things.

This is a very typical commercial domain and there is a typical solution for this. You need a ProductCatalog domain that will have products with ProductId. Both Sales and Purchase will reference aggregates from ProductCatalog by ProductId but have their own, independent aggregates with own ids and they basically have no need to know about each other unless your purchasing has some impact on sales (and it usually does by enabling sales to sell more when PO is placed or request to purchase goods that run out of stock). You will probably also need a Stock or Warehouse domain that will also reference products from the ProductCatalog domain. Events from both Sales and Purchase domains will directly affect the domain that holds the stock level.

Comment: I agree about the question being way too long :-) tho the first version was shorter (and IMO way better) but raised misunderstandings about my struggle, so i decided to explicit everything...

Comment: so in short, if i get you right, the correct way is SalesBC's and PurchaseBC's ProductAggregate holding a reference to the  CatalogProductId, right?

Comment: so the answer my first question's version `Should Sales and Logisitics Aggregates contains an PurchasedProductId ?` is simply yes... (even tho i'm aware the linguistic is probably not appropriate)

Comment: 'IMO the question is way too long' - Either answer the question directly or don't. There's no need to throw that remark in there. IMO it was great the the OP actually gave a broad context into the specific problem. If you think the question is too long - and you have to spend an extra 60 seconds reading it - then, don't read it, or answer it. Just leave a comment on the question. That's what comments are for. Answers on the other hand are for providing answers (surprise), not for snarly remarks, made by ivory tower dwelling DDD elitists.

Comment: @AaronHS You could have just edited my answer and see if it passes the review instead of lecturing someone in a long comment, thank you.

Answer (score -1):

DDD shares many common principles with SOA. As they rely on bounded contexts, domains do not know about each other. They communicate with notifications. These notifications can be embodied by DTOs, that are supported by contracts. In the present example, ProductId would figure in the DTO as a property. Once the notification is produced by a BC, it is consumed by another (as output from a table polling process, or after a transmission on a service bus...). The product is rehydrated in the consumer BC from the database, given its ProductId. The product lives in every BC where it makes sense. I think you are missing the BC. Are you ?

Comment: Thx I really appreciate ur concern! But : A) i dont think i'm missing the bounded context as I'm describing 3 of them B)as added in my edit, i know about events dispatching, i even store them (write side) and play'em back to restore the AR to current state. I dont store any entity state anywhere. I'm going to re-edit my post to make my point clearer. But again, thx for ur effort and ur concern.

Comment: -1: DDD intrinsically has nothing to do with SOA, and definitely does not imply remote execution.  DDD's Bounded Contexts do happen to make good SOA service boundaries.

Comment: DDD is not SOA. DDD does not imply remote execution. I don't know where you got this ideas but definitely not in Evans' book.

Comment: My comprehension of SOA makes me think something like this : http://www.jnsk.se/weblog/posts/SOA-QDDDTheOpposite.htm

Comment: @Alexey : you're right, and that's why I did not say SOA is DDD. From a business perspective, when a BC raises an event, you expect it to be handled, that's why (from a business perspective), DDD architecture deals with service oriented systems. As you said, DDD and SOA meet well together when the service boundaries meet the domain boundaries, and if we consider SOA is not about webservices only, it is about handling messages. I agree both underlying philosophies can be considered being very different, but they can meet very well.